# C# HtmlAgilityPack получить значение ноды

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Как с помощью HtmlAgilityPack мне получить значение иммено с тега p (в данному примере - `France`) из следующего фрагмента?

```
<p class="pclass">
  France<br />
  <span class="sclass1">COOK & SHARE</span><br />
  <span class="sclass2">Hall</span>
</p>
```

пробовал так

```
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[@class='pclass']");
var country = node.InnerText;
```

но получаю общий innerText.

Comment: `node.InnerHtml;` ?

Comment: @tym32167, нет. https://dotnetfiddle.net/H3J6vt

Comment: `var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("p[@class='pclass']").FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();` ?

Comment: Можно использовать такой xpath: `//p[@class='pclass']/text()`.